# Getting count of rows from one table where at least one related item from another table matches criteria

Tags: mysql

I have 'products' table and related 'variations' table, one product can have one or more variations. 'variations' table has 'status' column, its value can be 0 or 1. I want to get the number of products (COUNT()) which have at least one variation of status 1. How to make a query that would do that?
[EDIT]
Ok, I thought that if I simplify the question I will get away with the table structure, but, here we go (only columns relevant to the question and some mock data):

It's actually 3 linked tables:
table 1: 'products'

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t-shirt |
| 2 | shoes |
| 3 | shorts |

table 2: variations

| id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |

table 3: stock

| variation_id | quantity | status [0 or 1] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 15 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 |

So, with this data, I want to know how many products there are that have at least 1 of its 'variations' of 'status' 1 - in this example it would be 2 (product 1 and 3 have some variations with status 1, product 2 does not).

Comment: Please add table structure and sample data.  This is a bare minimum for your question here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `SUM` all the quantity `GROUP BY` products.id with criteria is stock.status equal 1.

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM Products pr
LEFT JOIN Variations va ON pr.id = va.product_id
LEFT JOIN Stock st ON st.variation_id = va.id
WHERE st.status = 1
GROUP BY pr.id
```

Comment: This is somehow a way around it as I need count of products that have at least one of its variations of status 1, not count of their quantity - but I modified the Select part to 'SELECT COUNT(pr.id) AS product_count' then get the count of rows returned by the query.  For putting me on a right track I accept this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Join two tables and apply where filter on status column

```
select count(*) as cnt
from
products p
join variations v
on p.product_id = v.product_id
where status = 1
```